# How to display battery discharge rate in watts, Windows 8 + perfmon

Tags: windows-8, battery, perfmon

Windows 'perfmon' utility allows to display graphs for different counters. One of them is Battery -> "Discharge rate" that can be spotted in the internet as a good way to examine battery discharge. I have tried to use it on 2 different laptops running Windows 8, but was surprised that it always shows "1.0" as it's value, not an amount of watts used by laptop as illustrated in many screenshots in internet :(. Is it any way to make it display watts or it's broken/not intended to be used on windows 8/all my laptops don't report battery discharge rate to windows?

Both laptops also running BatteryBar PRO that display discharge rate in watts perfectly well.

Updated

To clarify the things: I need discharge graph, not a current discharge value (BatteryBar displays current value without any problems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to use [HWiNFO](http://www.hwinfo.com/download.php) in conjunction with its [GenericLogViewer](http://www.hwinfo.com/addons.php) (guide [here](http://www.hwinfo.com/forum/Thread-LogViewer-for-HWINFO-is-available)) addon. HWiNFO should be able to collect discharge rates in its sensor mode, and GenericLogViewer includes graphing.

[[image: Screenshot of GenericLogViewer]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scm2G.png) <sup>Image takenfrom [the user guide](http://www.hwinfo.com/forum/Thread-LogViewer-for-HWINFO-is-available)</sup>

---

I currently do not have a Windows laptop available, so I am unable to test. I do remember that HWiNFO definitely does show CPU power draw, and vaguely recall the same for the battery. I'll test as soon as possible.

Comment: Hello. I have checked HWInfo - it shows only "remaining capacity". Of course, discharge rate can be calculated from remaining capacity - but this requires lots of post-processing :(.

Comment: @EyeofHell Ah, right. Sorry about that. You may be able to approximate something with the CPU power usage, though - that normally makes up a large amount of the battery usage. At the very least, it's the most variable part of it (CPUs can go from a couple Watts to >25 W).

Answer (score 9):

In windows 8 you can Use Command Prompt to achieve this  :

1.Navigate to Command Prompt

2.Type `powercfg /batteryreport`

3.Under Recent Usage Section you could find the detailed report

[image]

4.At battery usage Section you could find the graph

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but graph shows charge level, not discharge rate :(

Answer (score 5):

You can use [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) for that. It not only shows the total charge of your battery and its wear level, but also how much energy is drawn from it per second.

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, BatteryBar Pro displays discharge rate perfectly fine  but i need a graph. How HWMonitor can display graph?

Comment: Did you even look at the link I gave you? It says clearly on their page: 

"Graph Generator
Save monitoring data and generate logging graphs as bitmap files."

Comment: Also, you don't say a word in your original post about needing a graph.

Comment: Thanks, i have updated the question. Where is no "Graph Generator" text on the page you have specified - maybe it's inside an embedded advertisement corresponding to your search request or some commercial/pro version?

Comment: Yeah, it's a feature of the pro version: 

http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor-pro.html

But if you only need it a couple of times you should be able to run it in test mode. The only limitation if I remember correctly was that upon startup HWMonitor randomizes which system values it shows. Just restart it until the battery sensor shows up and you should be good to go. Other than that it should be fully functional, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Thanks again! I have checked trial version. It didn't show discharge rate - only current capacity.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a Laptop handy to check myself, but it should look like this: http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=363600 The "Current Capacity" value would be the one you'd want to graph, but if it doesn't show up then this might be a limitation of the trial. You could try restarting the software a couple of times seeing if it shows up, or use an older version in the hopes that it included it in the trial (I know it did that when I used it) or you could just bite the bullet and buy it.

Comment: You could also lobby the author of OpenHardwareMonitor - a free HWMonitor clone - to include battery support. OHM has by far better graph options available than HWMon, but it doesn't show any battery values. This wouldn't be a quick solution though, but a long term one.

Comment: I really don't see in HWmonitor the energy drawn per second. Where do you see that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the free [BattStat](http://users.rcn.com/tmtalpey/BattStat/), which does charge-graphs.
(I don't know if it works correctly on Windows 8.)

A possible shareware is [BatteryMon](http://www.passmark.com/products/batmon.htm) ($24).

Comment: BattStat don't display discharge rate graph on both my laptops, just like displayed on it'w own screenshots - corresponding field have "--" as a value and no graph. BatteryMon only display current charge graph, not a discharge rate graph.

Comment: It looks like discharge rate is universally overlooked. Perhaps it's assumed that charge rate is enough, or maybe the difference between the two is unclear.